# How to find if value is not present in array then write missing value to variable?

Tags: arrays, bash, comparison

I have some known values: `10 20 30 40 50 60 70`. I have an array containing some output generated by a command.  I want to find if any of the known values are missing in the array, if so write the first missing value to a variable.

For example, the first value missing in the array is `20`, so I want to set `variable=20`.

I have tried various methods to do this, but my limited bash knowledge is not helping here. Looping through multiple arrays, looping through statements. I don't have any working code.

```
array=( 1 2 10 30 40 )

if [ "$i" -ne "10" ] ; then
    variable="10"
    break
elif [ "$i" -ne "20" ] ; then
    variable="20"
    break
elif [ "$i" -ne "30" ] ; then
    variable="30"
    break
elif [ "$i" -ne "40" ] ; then
    variable="40"
    break
elif [ "$i" -ne "50" ] ; then
    variable="50"
    break
elif [ "$i" -ne "60" ] ; then
    variable="60"
    break
elif [ "$i" -ne "70" ] ; then
    variable="70"
    break
else
    echo "no values available"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
l="10 20 30 40 50 60 70"             # list of numbers
a=( 1 2 10 30 40 )                   # given array

b=" ${a[*]} "                        # convert array to list, anchor = space

v=''                                 # empty variable
for i in $l; do
  if [[ "$b" != *" $i "* ]]; then    # $i is NOT found in $b
    v=$i
    break
  fi
done

echo v=$v                            # print the result
```

Comment: Why did you add `*` around $i?

Answer (score 0):

With Bash≥4.0, you can use associative arrays and have a rather clean code as follows:

```
# declare the values you want:
wanted=( {10..70..10} )  # shortcut for wanted=( 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 )
# values you have:
array=( 1 2 10 30 40 )

# Make an associative array from the values you have, so that lookup
# is faster and cleaner (and correct!):
declare -A array_ass=()
for k in "${array[@]}"; do
    array_ass[$k]=1  # 1 is a dummy (non-empty) value. Put anything you like
done

# Now check that the values from wanted are in array_ass:
missing=
for k in "${wanted[@]}"; do
    [[ ${array_ass[$k]} ]] && continue
    # If we're here, the key k isn't in array!
    missing=$k
    break
done

if [[ $missing ]]; then
    echo "The value $missing is missing in array!"
else
    echo "All good!"
fi
```

Not to mention: all this will work with any type of variables, even those containing spaces, newlines, glob characters, etc. (except the empty string).